# What are some ways to store and recover numbers in this situation?

Tags: java, arrays, list, simulator

So i'm going to be running a simulator that plays craps.

My assignment requires me to run the sim 10,000,000 times.

None of that is an issue; I have the sim made and I know how to run in and I know how to create the required variables.

What I'm unsure of, is how I should go about storing the results of each game?

What I need to find in the end is:

Average # of Rolls Per Game
Max # of Rolls in a game
number of games that needed more than 30 rolls
number of wins
number of losses
probability of a win
longest sequence of wins and longest sequence of losses

All easy enough, I'm just not sure how to store 10,000,000 numbers and then access them easily.

For example the first: 
Average number of rolls
should I create an arraylist that has 10,000,000 items in it? add one item at the end of each game and then add them all up and divide by 10,000,000?

I realize this should work, I'm just wondering if there is another way, or perhaps a better (more efficient) way.

New part to this question:
Can I return more than one value from a method? Currently the simulation runs 10,000,000 times and returns a win or loss from each time. But I also need it to return the number of rolls from each game... Otherwise I can't figure out the values for avg rolls and highest number of rolls and number of games over 30 rolls.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Any particular reason as to why you need exactly 10,000,000 numbers? If so, what do you intend to store in the list?

Comment: Why do you need to store the results of each run? You can calculate all the summary statistics on the fly.

Comment: NirmalGeo: It was just part of the assignment to run the Sim 10,000,000 times. There would most likely be more than one array one would store game wins and losses as 1's and 0's; one would store number of rolls from each game.

Comment: Perception: I'm working on that method now; as it seems like the best route.. It's just a matter of figuring out all my variables and how to collect their data. Something that takes me quite a bit of time at this point, as I'm very new to Java!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to maintain array for any of the statistics you want.

For *average number of rolls per game*, just keep a variable, say `cumulativeNumberOfRolls`; after every game, just output the number of rolls in that game and add it to this variable. When all simulations are done, just divide this value by total number of simulations (10,000,000).

For *max. number of rolls*, again keep a single variable, say `maxRolls`; after every game, output the number of rolls in that game and compare that with this variable. If the number of rolls in this game is greater, then just update `maxRolls` with the new value. Try the same approach - of having a single variable and updating it after every game - to get the value for *games that required more than 30 rolls*, *number of wins* and *number of losses*. If you face problems, we can discuss them in comments.

For *longest sequence of wins and losses*, you would need to maintain a bunch of variables:

- longest win sequence overall
- longest loss sequence overall
- current sequence count
- current sequence type (indicates if current sequence is a win sequence or loss sequence)

Here's the overview of the approach. 
After every game, compare the result of the game with the `current sequence type`. If they are same, for instance result of current game is win and the current sequence type is also a win, then just update the `current sequence count` and move on to the next game. If they are different, you need to consider two scenarios and do slightly different things for them. I'll explain for one - the result of current game is loss and the `current sequence type` is win. In this scenario, compare `current sequence count` with `longest win sequence overall` and if it (`current sequence count`) is greater then just update the `longest win sequence overall`. After this, change the `current sequence type` to loss and set the `current sequence count` to 1.

Extend the above approach for the second scenario - the result of the current game is win and the `current sequence type` is loss. If you have clarifications, feel free to post back in comments.

Comment: Do you think it would be favorable to do these as final static variables? for example 
final static int win=0;
final static int loss=1;

and then create a variable "seqType"
and declare it as either win or loss...? Thank you for all of this! Very helpful!

Comment: You are thinking on the correct lines; the sequence types should be constants. A better way would be to use enums; define an enum, say GameResult, that will have literals for win and loss and seqType will be a variable of enum type GameResult. As for other variables, the preferred way would be to have them as private member variables; In case you have code spanning multiple classes that access/update these variables, then define public get/set methods to access/update these variables. I'm glad it helped.

Comment: @OscarWilde just a reminder, if the answer helped solve your problem, do up-vote and/or accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just calculate the statistics as you go without storing them.  For instance, if you hava an "average" field in your class, then after each simulation `average = ((number of rolls this game) + (total rolls so far)) / (number of games so far)`.  The same could be done for the other statistics.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of just doing them as I went.. just seemed like a lot to calculate at the end of each run; but not really any different than storing it all and then calculating at the end..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've got a fixed number of runs, so you might as well use an array rather than an arraylist (faster). It seems to me that you actually only need two total arrays: one listing the outcome of each game (maybe true/false for win/lose), and one with the number of rolls in that game. You fill these up as you run the simulations; then you get to do a bunch of simple math involving one array or the other to get your stats. That seems like the best way to go about it to me; I don't think you're going to get much more efficient without a lot of undue effort.